# Can an https website access a https unsecure rest api?

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, https

My website is https with a certification but my rest API is https but not secure (when you navigate to the website the browser says the certificate is valid but the api says its not valid).

Can my server make requests to it? I am getting connection timed out type errors and I'm not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Yes, you can set your server up to ignore all SSL/TSL problems, but you _should_ really just fix your certificates

Comment: Would I be able to use the self-signed certificate somehow? My website would be the only thing to access the API. It is running on Next js

Comment: Yes you can! HTTP clients typically have a way to supply it with root certificates. If your client can do this (and it's a server-side client), find out in the documentation of the client (or your SSL library). The key difference between self-signing and not is that the not-self-signed uses a root certificate that your system likely already recognizes. Also note that it's free these days to get real certificates, and taking that route might be easier. Check out letsencrypt

Comment: Thanks! I used letsencrypt for my website but I was having issues with the API and thought it might be easier to just use the self-signed.